# How can I implement Bulk insert in ASP.NET Core 1.0?

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-1.0

I want to import the data from database in .csv format and want to export .csv into my SQL server/Oracle database. I am using ASP.NET Core RC 1 at this moment. I looked into SQLBulkCopy class but the issue is that it is not ported to ASP.NET Core.

Can someone tell me how can I do it or is there any other compatible nuget package available (with ASP.NET Core)?

Comment: I'm trying to work through this specific issue as well. Did you have any luck?

Comment: No. I didn't find any solution till now.

Comment: Try this library: https://github.com/borisdj/EFCore.BulkExtensions

Comment: Well last week, .NET Standard 2.0 was announced and sqlbulkcopy is now available in ASP.NET Core. More details here..
http://www.talkingdotnet.com/whats-new-in-net-standard-2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.NET Standard 2.0 now supports many of the .NET framework libraries which means that SqlBulkCopy class can be used with ASP.NET Core. Dataset, Datatables and SQLBulkCopy will do the job for bulk insertion. Find more details about .NETStandard 2.0 [here](http://www.talkingdotnet.com/whats-new-in-net-standard-2/).

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft has added [SqlBulkCopy](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Data.SqlClient/src/System/Data/SqlClient/SqlBulkCopy.cs) to .NET Core, so you can bring it in as part of the `System.Data.SqlClient` NuGet package. I opted to use [FastMember](https://github.com/mgravell/fast-member) by @MarcGravell to handle the work of mapping my data, but you don't have to.

FastMember will take a collection of parameters, and a collection of objects, and pull the values off your objects that map to your collection of parameters. Really simplifies the code.

```cs
private async Task OutputPerformanceDataToStorage(List<PerformanceData> dataToSave)
{
    var storageParameters = new[] 
        {
            nameof(PerformanceData.PerformanceId),
            nameof(PerformanceData.IPAddress),
            nameof(PerformanceData.ControllerName),
            nameof(PerformanceData.ActionName),
            nameof(PerformanceData.ActionParameters),
            nameof(PerformanceData.ViewPath),
            nameof(PerformanceData.TotalRequestTimeInMilliseconds),
            nameof(PerformanceData.RequestStartedTimestamp),
            nameof(PerformanceData.RequestEndedTimestamp),
            nameof(PerformanceData.CreatedDateTime),
        };

    var sqlCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(this.connectionString, SqlBulkCopyOptions.Default);
    sqlCopy.DestinationTableName = "[Performance]";

    using (var reader = ObjectReader.Create(dataToSave, storageParameters))
    {
        await sqlCopy.WriteToServerAsync(reader);
    }
}

internal class PerformanceData
{
    public Guid PerformanceId;
    public double TotalRequestTimeInMilliseconds;
    public long RequestStartedTimestamp;
    public long RequestEndedTimestamp;
    public string IPAddress;
    public string ControllerName;
    public string ActionName;
    public string ViewPath;
    public string ActionParameters;
    public List<string> ActionParametersList;
    public DateTime CreatedDateTime;
}
```

Comment: How would you do it without using FastMember?

Comment: You would do it like any other usage of SqlBulkCopy. Create the mapping with SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping, DataRows and DataColumns. I'd recommend FastMember, you'll save yourself a lot of code

Comment: This won't work with dynamic list like 
OutputPerformanceDataToStorage<T>(List<T> dataToSave)